Connect Azure container app with azure app services resource hosted in different vnets
I am looking for a solution to develop an internal Azure Container Apps environment that ensures secure connectivity exclusively with selected resources, running on other platforms like App Services (in different vnets), while preventing exposure to the internet. This will involve:

Establishing Inbound and Outbound Connectivity:
Create a solution that facilitates controlled inbound connections from designated services while ensuring that Container Apps remain internal-only.

Implementing FQDN Endpoints for Service Discovery:
Ensure the solution supports Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDN) for seamless service discovery, adapting to the dynamic assignment of IP addresses.

Addressing Engineering Challenges:
Investigate and identify the necessary resources, including virtual networks, peerings, gateways, load balancers, and linked private DNS zones, to create a robust connectivity solution.


I have tried peering the Vnets where the container app and app service are hosted. What else do I need to do?

Develop a secure internal Azure Container Apps environment by integrating both Container Apps and App Services into Virtual Networks. Enable Private Endpoints to keep them internal-only and not exposed to the internet. Use a Private DNS zone for FQDN resolution, allowing dynamic IP management.


Connect Azure container app with azure app services resource hosted in different vnets.

To establish the secure internal azure container apps environment with controlled connectivity to other resources, such as app services in different VNETs, make sure to follow the below steps.

Ensure that both azure container apps and app services are integrated into azure virtual networks, if different vnets, you can use VNET peering for allow the different vnet communications.

Enable private endpoints for both container apps and app services to ensure they are only accessible from within the private network, not exposed to the public internet.

Create and link private DNS zones to VNets to enable FQDN resolution for the services. This helps to communicate using domain names instead of IP addresses.

Configure NSGs to control inbound and outbound traffic in VNets. Define rules that allow traffic only from specific sources and destinations, ensuring that only designated services can connect to container apps.


Reference: Provide a virtual network to an internal Azure Container Apps environment
Azure security baseline for Azure Container Apps
Considerations for using Container Apps in a multitenant solution
